# ogg в wav python

Tags: python, аудио, wav, ogg

Недавно задался вопросом - а как сконвертировать формат ogg в wav с помощью python? Просьба привести пример исполнения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте [так](https://pypi.org/project/PySoundFile/):

```
import soundfile as sf   #   pip install pysoundfile

data, samplerate = sf.read('existing_file.ogg')
sf.write('new_file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

Comment: А что делать, с ошибкой Error opening 'abb.ogg': File contains data in an unimplemented format?

Comment: я только что протестировал с несколькими OGG файлами из моей муз. коллекции - все отработало отлично...

Comment: @Иван, https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/issues/4247 - посмотрите может у вас та же проблема...